# Prove that the function f is strictly convex

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-regression, hessian-matrix

I came across this question when I self study my friends'note. He took data mining class in university and the question is like below and I cannot find answers from Google:
[image]

I know that to prove that function is strictly convex, I need to calculate the Hessian matrix and if Hess(x) is positive definite, then the function f is strictly convex. However, I have some problem deriving the Hessian matrix. Any help or hint is much appreciated!

Comment: The question is not specific. What sort of problems do you have?

Comment: sorry, I realise that the image is not properly displayed

Comment: I don't think that You have to calculate the Hessian here. There are other methods. Actually one can do it simply by definition here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $f(x)=0.5(\langle Ax,x\rangle-\langle b,x\rangle -\langle Ax,A^{-1}b>+\langle b,b\rangle )$.
So it is sufficient to show that $\langle A(tx+(1-t)y,tx+(1-t)y\rangle -\langle b,tx+(1-t)y\rangle -\langle A(tx+(1-t)y),A^{-1}b\rangle  <$
$<t(\langle Ax,x\rangle -\langle b,x\rangle -\langle Ax,A^{-1}b\rangle )$
$+(1-t)(\langle Ay,x\rangle -\langle b,y\rangle -\langle Ay,A^{-1}b\rangle )$ for each $t$ from $(0,1)$.
Eliminating equal terms on both sides leaves us with
$\langle A(tx+(1-t)y,tx+(1-t)y\rangle <t\langle Ax,x\rangle +(1-t)\langle Ay,y\rangle $.
So now it is about $\langle Ax,x \rangle$ being striktly convex for a positive definite $A$ which is a well known fact.

Comment: By the way, the hessian Matrix of $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is simply $A$. Could be easily calculated since $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\sum_{i,j} x_ia_{ij}x_j$

Comment: Thanks! I now get it. But is there a typo in your answer? f(x)=0.5(⟨Ax,x⟩−⟨b,x⟩−⟨Ax,A−1b>+⟨b,A−1b⟩) instead?

Comment: Yes, a typo, thanks.